# How to parse json in retrofit with dynamic key

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I have this response and I want to make model class of it using retrofit. I know how to make model class for each particular object but don't know about how make model class for first parent array.

```
[3]
0:  {
     user: {
            _id: "55e725b65656565d066037"
            photo: "https://graph.facebook.com/9884898989882/picture?height=300&width=300"
            provider: "facebook"
            username: "xyz"
           }
        url:"abc.com"
    }
1:  {
     user: {
            _id: "55e725b65656565d066037"
            photo: "https://graph.facebook.com/9884898989882/picture?height=300&width=300"
            provider: "facebook"
            username: "xyz"
           }
        url:"abc.com"
    }
2:  {
     user: {
            _id: "55e725b65656565d066037"
            photo: "https://graph.facebook.com/9884898989882/picture?height=300&width=300"
            provider: "facebook"
            username: "xyz"
           }
        url:"abc.com"
    }
```

Comment: use this. paste ur whole json response source in it it will give you a complete model class  http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score -1):

If your json looks like:

```
{
    "0": {
        "user": {
            "_id": "55e725b65656565d066037",
            "photo": "https://graph.facebook.com/9884898989882/picture?height=300&width=300",
            "provider": "facebook",
            "username": "xyz"
        },
        "url": "abc.com"
    },
    "1": {
        "user": {
            "_id": "55e725b65656565d066037",
            "photo": "https://graph.facebook.com/9884898989882/picture?height=300&width=300",
            "provider": "facebook",
            "username": "xyz"
        },
        "url": "abc.com"
    },
    "2": {
        "user": {
            "_id": "55e725b65656565d066037",
            "photo": "https://graph.facebook.com/9884898989882/picture?height=300&width=300",
            "provider": "facebook",
            "username": "xyz"
        },
        "url": "abc.com"
    }
}
```

You can create a model for elements "0", "1", etc.

```
public class Element {

    private User user;

    private String url;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public static class User {

        @SerializedName("_id")
        private String id;

        private String photo;

        private String provider;

        private String username;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getPhoto() {
            return photo;
        }

        public String getProvider() {
            return provider;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally you have to create Map for top json level

```
Map<String, Element> elements;
```

You can get elements like below:

```
elements.get("0");
```